# Android CalendarView in Support library

Tags: android, calendarview

I have been trying to make an app with a calendar view, but the one I have been using is not working when I try to scale it across multiple devices.

Does android have a calendarview in the support library? I need to use the calendar to pick a date.

Are there any other calendar views on github that are recommended?

Comment: What's the one you are using now?

Comment: check this [Calendar View](http://www.androidviews.net/2013/04/extendedcalendarview/)

Comment: @Nizam I was using this: https://code.google.com/p/android-calendar-view/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the user to pick a date you could use the third party [TimesSquare](https://github.com/square/android-times-square) component.

Comment: Thanks, but is there something a bit easier to implement? and does the support library have calendarviews?

Comment: The support library does not have any Calender component.